# Single Access Token from several endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I have a fundamental lack of understanding of implementing security with OAuth.  All of the examples I see use the same pattern, so I'm pretty confident my premise is wrong, and the examples are right!

Generally I see it added along these lines.

```
            .AddOAuth("auth", options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "id";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin");
            options.Scope.Add("scope");

            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://.../authorize";
            options.TokenEndpoint = "https://.../token";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://.../userinfo";

            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");


            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    context.RunClaimActions(user);
                }
            };
```

Now to my fundamental misunderstanding.  I want to make a demo application that, for example, has a couple of pages that show the result of some rest api calls.  These calls all require an access token.  Once the code reaches OnCreatingTicket, the access token has been acquired, and it is used to get data from the UserInformationEndpoint.  However, I have several different end points that I want the user to select from (and there may not even be a  "UserInformationEndpoint" for the api I'm trying to call..).

So, I think I have a bogus idea about how I'm supposed to do this.  Could someone spin me around and point me in the right direction?

Edit because its too long for a comment:

My requirement is just to write a demo app that demonstrates making calls to a api directory.

For the sake of the demo I just imagine a page with a series of links/buttons that take you to a page showing the data returned from different api calls.

In the example above (and all the examples i've seen so far) the authorization is setup at the server level and used to retrieve user information.  For my demo getting user information back and displaying it might be nice, but its not the end goal.  The fact that all of the examples center on using the toke a single time to get user info is what confuses me.  I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that I should get the token once and use it repeatedly from different points in the application.

I'm having trouble understanding if I am fundamentally misunderstanding how to approach this since I tend to imagine if all the examples I find are doing the same thing, they are doing it correctly.

Comment: what is your exact question. Do you lack end user information because you are missing user info endpoint ?  Have you thought of using openid connect ?

Comment: I updated the original question

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding your question also, even after the update.  I don't think there is one right way to get the user's info because all Single-Sign-Ons (SSOs) are a little different.  You should adapt your .AddOAuth() calls to the specific SSO you are adding.  In my example below I am assuming that the token is a JWT as some of the big SSOs are, so I am requesting the scope with the original sign-in.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the endpoint but the way I usually get the user's profile information is by adding scopes.  For example, if your endpoint allows access to user profiles, inside your oauth options, request that scope when you authenticate the user:

```
options.Scope.Add("profile");
```

This should get it done with less traffic back and forth to the endpoint.

For example, I recently had the same issue with the Google API.  I don't remember the exact name of the scope but I requested "profile" scope or something like that and it sent me email, first name, and last name.  When I didn't request this scope it only sent me the user id.

Comment: For getting user info in a token, you usually need an ID token from OpenID Connect (OAuth2 extension). Access tokens are usually just random strings (some OAuth2 implementations use JWT, but there is not specification for what it should contain).

Comment: In OnCreatingTicket the auth token has already been acquired.  I kind of thought I should be simply saving the token for later use, but all of the examples immediately make an additional call to get user info.  Ultimately I don't necessarily care about any user info i just need the ticket. 
I have successfully made a different API call in place of UserInfo, however this did not feel like the correct thing to do.